# Python Command Line App

Tags: python, command-line, python-2.7

I am unsure on how to implement an app command line method.

These would be my flags: 
-g (male/female) 
-p (phone number) 
-r (reasons) 
-e (endings)
-o (output name)

Each one of the flags corresponds to a variable defined by the same single letter. Am I on the right track or can you point me in the right direction?

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Voice Mail App')

parser.add_argument('-o', action="store", dest="o")
parser.add_argument('-g', action="store", dest='g')
parser.add_argument('-p', action="store", dest="p")
parser.add_argument('-r', action="store", dest="r")
parser.add_argument('-e', action="store", dest='e')


print parser.parse_args(['-o', '-g', '-p', '-r', '-e', '5'])
```

Comment: How do you know what you have doesn't work? Have you tried running it?

Comment: I get:usage: My Python Project - voicemail.py [-h] [-o O] [-g G] [-p P] [-r R]
                                            [-e E]
My Python Project - voicemeail.py: error: argument -o: expected one argument

Process finished with exit code 2

Answer (score 2):

Sure you're on the right track.  But, your arguments all require information to be passed to them.  e.g.:

```
print parser.parse_args(['-o','Joe', 
                         '-g','male',
                         '-p','867-5309',
                         '-r','because I can',
                         '-e', '5'])
```